# how to access property from list

Tags: c#, properties

If I have the following code and want to iterate the list of vehicles and display the Price, how can I access that property?

```
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class ElectricalDriven : Vehicle
    {
        public string SuperChargerCord { get; set; }
    }

    public class GasolinDriven : Vehicle
    {
        public string GasolineTank { get; set; }
    }

        var myListOfVechicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        myListOfVechicles.Add(new ElectricalDriven { Name = "Tesla", Price = "100 000", SuperChargerCord = "Yellow cord"});
        myListOfVechicles.Add(new GasolinDriven { Name = "Ford", Price = "50 000", GasolineTank = "Large VZ Tank"});


        foreach (var row in myListOfVechicles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"- {row.Name}");
        }
```

Comment: Why isn't `Price` defined in `Vechicle`?  You could create an interface that exposes `Price` and make it a list of that interface type, but more context would be needed to determine if that's an acceptable.  Alternatively you could cast to `dynamic` and rely on runtime checking.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but probably you are asking this because the design can have another spin. Probably you would like to have a "Priceable vehicle" class, and define the property there.

Comment: In real use there would be different properties for the classes "ElectricalDriven" and "GasolinDriven", thats why...

Comment: @Magnus But if `Price` is a common property for both, it should be in a subclass or interface.  Otherwise there's no commonality between them (other then they have the same name).

Comment: I don't understand. Since Price is in Vehicle, when iterating on your list you should be able to get Price from any classes, from vehicle to its subclasses !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a unique property for both Electric and Gasoline vehicles, and be able to retrieve its value from the generic vehicle class, you can declare a virtual method and override it in the inheriting classes:

```
 public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string GetCustomProperty() { return string.Empty; }
}

public class ElectricalDriven : Vehicle
{
    public string ElectricalVehicleProperty { get; set; }
    public override string GetCustomProperty() { return ElectricalVehicleProperty; }
}

public class GasolinDriven : Vehicle
{
    public string GasolinVehicleProprety { get; set; }
    public override string GetCustomProperty() { return GasolinVehicleProprety; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myListOfVechicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        myListOfVechicles.Add(new ElectricalDriven { Name = "Tesla", ElectricalVehicleProperty = "100 000" });
        myListOfVechicles.Add(new GasolinDriven { Name = "Ford", GasolinVehicleProprety = "50 000" });

        foreach (var row in myListOfVechicles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Price: " + row.GetCustomProperty()); //will output 100,000 and 50,000
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is pretty nice!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Vehicle` does not *have* a `Value` property, so you can't ask for it in a type-safe manner.

Some options are:

- Override `ToString` so that the *class* determines what is displayed:
- Add a `virtual` method to `VEhivel like`GetDescription`that returns a string if you don't want that string to override`ToString`
- Move `Price` to `Vehicle` or a subtype that `ElectricalDriven` and `GasolinDriven` both inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach you can check if the current 'row' is ElectricalDriven or GasolinDriven with the 'is' operator and then cast the row to the matched concrete implementation. Should be something like that:

```
if (row is ElectricalDriven)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Price: {((ElectricalDriven)row).Price}");
}
else if (row is GasolinDriven)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Price: {((GasolinDriven)row).Price}");
}
```

However, you can see that the more different vehicles, the more ifs. You should probably move the price property in the base class or in an interface.

EDIT: Seeing that the author moved the price property to the Vehicle class, you can now access it just like you accessed the Name property.

Comment: While technically correct, there are cleaner ways to do this that don't require type-checking/casting.

Comment: @DStanley You are right. That's why I mentioned, that the property should be moved to the base class, for example. I just tried to answer, according to the given program structure.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
var myListOfVechicles = new List<Vehicle>();
myListOfVechicles.Add(new ElectricalDriven { Name = "Tesla", Price = "100 000" });
myListOfVechicles.Add(new GasolinDriven { Name = "Ford", Price = "50 000" });
```

The compiler will assign an object of the subclass (like ElectricalDriven) to object to the base class (Vehicle) ***after*** implicitly converting it to the base class type.

Know because of this conversion, when you are trying to access that object you're accessing an object that only have the base class members which is only `Name`.

To be able to access `Price` you need to *explicitly* cast the object to the subclass type before accessing its members. The simplest for example you can try this:

```
   string name, price;
    foreach (var item in myListOfVechicles)
    {
        name = item is ElectricalDriven ? 
                       (item as ElectricalDriven).Name : 
                       (item as GasolinDriven).Name;
        price = item is ElectricalDriven ? 
                        (item as ElectricalDriven).Price :
                        (item as GasolinDriven).Price;

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name} - Price: {price}");
    }
```